# Filter an array in iOS shortcuts - how?

Tags: ios, arrays, filter, shortcut

I have an array like this:

```
  "vehicleStatus": [
    {
      "key": "TU_STATUS_PRIMARY_VOLT",
      "value": "3.6"
    },
    {
      "key": "TU_STATUS_PRIMARY_CHARGE_PERCENT",
      "value": "100"
    },
    {
      "key": "TU_STATUS_GSM_MODEM",
      "value": "FUNCTIONING"
    },
    {
      "key": "DOOR_IS_ALL_DOORS_LOCKED",
      "value": "TRUE"
    }
]
```

I want to retrieve the value of DOOR_IS_ALL_DOORS_LOCKED by filtering the array and without the "Repeat with each item" action.

I already filter arrays in other tools, JavaScript, Power Automate etc.

Is this possible in iOS Shortcuts?

I tried looping through all 97 items in this array and using IF condition to set a variable if the condition is met and then using that variable later, but it's long winded and takes too long for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

### 1). For loop

First Solution of your problem, is already you have done.
Maybe you have done this by using for loop manually.

so second Option is

---

---

### 2). System Iterative

```swift
if let arrEle = vehicleStatus.first { $0.key == "DOOR_IS_ALL_DOORS_LOCKED"} {
    print(arrEle.value)
}
```

or

```swift
if let arrEle = vehicleStatus.first { ($0 as? NsDict)?["key"] == "DOOR_IS_ALL_DOORS_LOCKED"} {
    print((arrEle as? NsDict)?["value"] as? String)
}
```

or

```swift
if let arrEle = vehicleStatus.first { ($0 as? NsDict)?["key"] == "DOOR_IS_ALL_DOORS_LOCKED"}, 
   let val = (arrEle as? NsDict)?["value"] as? String {

    print(val)
}
```

you can change data management by

---

---

### 3). Dictionary

If 'vehicleStatus' has all data like you provide, then all data must be manage by dictionary.

```swift
let vehicleStatus = [
    [
        "key" : "TU_STATUS_PRIMARY_VOLT",
        "value": "3.6"
    ],
    [
        "key" : "TU_STATUS_PRIMARY_CHARGE_PERCENT",
        "value": "100"
    ],
    [
        "key" : "TU_STATUS_GSM_MODEM",
        "value" : "FUNCTIONING"
    ],
    [
        "key" : "DOOR_IS_ALL_DOORS_LOCKED",
        "value": "TRUE"
    ]
]
print(vehicleStatus)

let dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: vehicleStatus.map{ ($0["key"]!, $0["value"]! ) })
print(dict)
```